# Search within a link using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a web page which contains several static links (Link to some other web pages).

Now i want a search functionality in which user want the list of all those link (link present in the web page) in which some specific word (Entered by user) exist.

Could someone please share the logic which i can implement to get this functionality working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be search for everything that contains `href`.

Comment: Do you want to search by the URL or Link Text

Comment: please provide some sample code

Comment: I want to search the content within the link provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
   function callFunction(){
      var links = new Array();
      var searchString = document.getElementById("searchString").value;
      var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
      for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
          var content = list[i].innerHTML;
          if(content.indexOf(searchString)>=0){
             links.push(list[i].href);
          }
      }
    alert(links);
   }

</script>


<body>
   <a href="abc">link1</a><br>
   <a href="xyz">link2</a><br>

   Enter Text:<input type="text" id="searchString"/>
   <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="callFunction()"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i want to search within the content of the lick provided.

Comment: Updated the answer to search in link text

Comment: i have two links one is link one which is attached to below content <HTML>

<HEAD>

</HEAD>
<body>
   Abhay is adding abc
</body>

</HTML> and other one with below content <HTML>

<HEAD>

</HEAD>
<body>
   Abhay is adding def
</body>

</HTML> now if i search abc whcih is a part of link1 then it should show link1, or if i search def then it should show link2.  I hope it is more clear, by the way thanks for your efforts.